# How can I compare the JSON ARRAY I am getting from API, with a normal Java Array present in the CSV file?

Tags: arrays, json, comparator

I am a little stuck with the operation of comparing JSON ARRAY and simple java string array. So, I have a CSV file which contains the data in one column I have the data in the form of a String Array.

```
Ex-{ "https://google.com", "https://stackoverflow.com", "https://directi.com", "https://facebook.com" }
```

While calling the API I get a JSONARRAY in the form:

```
["https://google.com",
 "https://facebook.com",
 "https://stackoverflow.com",
 "https://directi.com"
 ]
```

I want to compare these two values, I am not able to find any solution.

I thought of extracting the JSONARRAY values and store it in a string and then compare, but the issue is that the CSV file is storing the whole array as a single variable and not a string. Also, the index values are different in API and String. But the data is the same.

```
Example: String CSV_value = { "https://google.com", "https://stackoverflow.com", "https://directi.com", "https://facebook.com" }
```

How can I do this comparison, can anyone please tell.